# CSS table padding issue where text jumps to the next line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been trying to get the padding on my table to work but the cell content keeps going to the next line like this :

[image]

But I need it like this with the padding:

[image]

The problem seems to arise only while using percentages in my padding property.

```css
td,
th {
  padding: 32px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Book</th>
    <th>Author</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Let Us C</td>
    <td>Balagurusamy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above works just fine however, the below syntax is causing the problem.

```css
td,
th {
  padding: 3.2%;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Book</th>
    <th>Author</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Let Us C</td>
    <td>Balagurusamy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas how I can use percentage and still get the content to stay on the same line?

P.S: I tried the `cellpading` attribute but it is apparently not supported in HTML5.

Edit: Using `white-space: nowrap` caused the text to overlap with the borders:

[image]

Comment: `td { white-space: nowrap; }` would prevent the text breaking on to multiple lines.

Comment: Didn't work- caused the text to overlap with the borders

Comment: Your example works the 3.2% are just very small. Increase it to 6.2% or higher and you get the same result as in the first example.

Comment: @RNH - still doesn't work. The problem is that the width is staying constant and not increasing according the content size as it should.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can not reproduce your bug. The white-space solution works for me. Are you sure your columns do not have a fixed width?

Comment: Firefox developer edition and no it does not have fixed width. BTW does adding a tr element using JS cause width to be fixed?

Comment: The html file:```<html>
 <head>
  <title>List Page</title>
  <script src="./list.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <center><h1>The List </h1></center>
    <center><table id="table">     
     <tr>
      <th>Book</th>
      <th>Author</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><p>Let Us C</p></td>
      <td>Balagurusamy</td>
     </tr>
    </table></center>
 </body>
</html>```

Comment: The css file:```body{
 background-color: #ffe4b5;
}
table,td,th{
 width: auto;
 border:1px solid black;
}
table{
 border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th,td{ 
 padding: 3.2%; 
}```

Comment: The JS file:```var list = [['Let Us C','Balagurusamy'],['My Life','Anonymous']];
window.onload = function(){ 
 var table = document.getElementById("table");
 for(i in list){
  result = add(list[i]);
  table.appendChild(result);
 }
}
function add(arr){
 var elems = new Array(arr.length);
 var resultantElement = document.createElement("tr");
 for(i in arr){
  elems[i] = document.createElement("td");
  elems[i].id = "table_data_"+i;
  elems[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(''+arr[i]));  
  resultantElement.appendChild(elems[i]);
 }
 return resultantElement;
}```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your CSS.

```
 display: inline-block;
 word-break: break-word;
```

or you can also use this if it works for you.

```
word-break: break-word;
white-space: unset !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Book</th>
    <th>Author</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Let Us C</td>
    <td>Balagurusamy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```